# Edit a wordpress stylesheet and save using php & ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to create a settings section on my site so I can change the styles, so if i select blue, it will change the background to blue and save the external stylesheet so that when i reload the page, it will still be blue.

I have no idea how to do this so it's just basic code for the moment.

I understand that I need the html checkbox code and jquery will then take note of what's being selected, ajax & php will then update the stylesheet.

I just don't know how?

Here's the html code

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="colours" value="red" checked> red
  <input type="radio" name="colours" value="blue">blue
</div>
```

Here's the css

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
html, body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
```

Here's the php i have so far:

```
// edit these values to match your database information
$server = "localhost";
$user = "******";
$password = "*******";
$db = "******";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password); 

if (!$con) {
die("database connection error");
} else {

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$file = 'get_site_url();/style.css';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Write the contents back to the file
$test = file_put_contents($current, $current);

echo '

<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="stylesheet">'. $current .'</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
';

}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside the general warning to restrict this panel from the whole world, you will want to start with a check on the submitted form. You may want to check for $_POST['submit'] and give the submit button a name:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="stylesheet"><?php echo $current; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in PHP check if submit is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fp = fopen( get_site_url() .'/style.css', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['stylesheet']);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Not sure what your sql needs are here, but you're not using that connection.
Whole thing would be:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $stylesheet = $_POST['stylesheet'];
    $stylesheet = preg_replace('/(background:)(.*)(;)/', '$1'.$_POST['colours'].'$3', $_POST['colours'], $stylesheet);
    $fp = fopen( get_site_url() .'/style.css', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $stylesheet);
    fclose($fp);
}
else
{
    $filename = get_site_url() .'/style.css';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $stylesheet = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="stylesheet"><?php echo $stylesheet; ?></textarea>
<input type="radio" name="colours" value="red" checked> red
<input type="radio" name="colours" value="blue">blue
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Assuming `get_site_url()` resolves to the server path to that file. You may want to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/style.css'` depending on where this file actually resides.

Yet another side note, this sample also assumes you're starting with the content of the style sheet. You can use regular expressions to find and replace the value of the style you want to edit. You will want to get more specific in an actual case though cause this will replace anything between background: and ;

Here's the link to using ajax in a wp plugin:
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

It's pretty simple to set up a plugin that acts as a request handler for your ajax needs

Comment: using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/style.css'` is a `no-no`.. it will break on multisite. use only internal WP functions...